# Xbox Emulator for Linux?

Tags: games, emulation

new user here. I would like to know if there is a good Xbox emulator for Ubuntu 22.04? I really just wanted to play [Dino Crisis 3](https://www.emugames.net/xbox-roms/dino-crisis-3/). Sadly, it's an Xbox-exclusive game and my Xbox console has long been broken. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Google: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Xbox+Emulator+for+Linux%3F&bshm=rime/1  "I would like to know if there is a good Xbox emulator " asking for opinions is off topic on AU

Comment: Most likely no. Consoles are proprietary hardware.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I just wanted to ask those with experience with Ubuntu 22.04. I just installed it, so I don't know what to expect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is an emulator called xemu
You download and install it by downloading the appimage file here :

[xemu download page](https://xemu.app/docs/download/#download-for-linux)

Comment: Running appimage file is so easy just click on it and then you will see the app starts without any installation

Comment: Thank you thank you.. I normally use Windows and thought I'd give Ubuntu a try since my father is a Linux user. I usually play RetroArch on my phone, but my phone can't handle anything other than GBA. lol. Thanks again for the quick response. I'm genuinely surprised. God bless.

Comment: Your welcome , it's 3 years since I switched to Ubuntu and if you know how to work with it it's kinda better than windows